# Rectangle with largest area under y=x^2, that lies under y=a

Tags: calculus

[image]

Find the dimensions of a rectangle with largest area which fits inside the graph of the parabola $y=x^2$ that lies below the line $y=a$ (where $a$ is a constant value) so that the top side of the rectangle lies on the horizontal line $y=a$.

See above image.

My main question: do I express the dimensions in terms of the constant, $a$?

My working so far:

$A=2x*(a-x^2)$

$=2ax-2x^3$

$dA/dx = 2a-6x^2$

$0=2a-6x^2$

$6x^2=2a$

$x^2=2a/6$

$x^2=a/3$

$x=\sqrt{a/3}$

Thus the dimensions are: $$2\cdot \sqrt{a/3} \cdot (a - \sqrt{a/3})$$

Or is there an actual number dimension I can deduce?

Answer (score 1):

In your problem, $a$ is to be interpreted as a fixed number.

It is obvious that the answer depends on $a$ (just imagine putting $a$ way higher on the graph; the maximum area is gonna change); this implies that is not possible to find an "actual" value, because it has to depend on $a$

So you've found the dimension in terms of $a$, and it appears to me that they are correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is correct, just the last line is wrong (you used $x$ instead of $x^2$ in the parentheses). The result for the area should be

$$A=2\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}\left(a-\frac{a}{3}\right)=\frac{4a}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}$$